# Write a shell which can embed other application and run as a separate process

Tags: c++, winapi, shell

I found an interesting article from HP website. They wrote a TouchSmart Shell application, and it allows other applications to embed in that shell, and run as a separate process. Of course, HP defined some restrictions with the embedded application. I don’t know if C++ and Win32 can do similar thing?
http://www.touchsmartcommunity.com/article/95/An-HP-TouchSmart-Application-Development-Guidelines-Primer/?textpage=1

Comment: Can you make it a bit clearer exactly what your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this what all the unix shells do? Embed applications into themselves. I hope I have understood your question correctly. A similar thing can definitely be done in Win32. MSYS (Minimal SYStem) and Cygwin all do the same. They have their own shells, though I would assume they're written in C and not in C++

Comment: As in

if(pid=fork())
  #parent, child pid is pid
else
  exec("command")

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I've missed something, but TouchSmart just looks like a way of starting a .NET application from within it.  There are probably some API's that you need to call into for correct presentation or events to hook up to.